# keep getting error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'piecash'

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to run `csv2cash` on my machine. I've installed `Python 3.6` & cloned the git repo to my machine (https://github.com/jrwrigh/csv2cash), entered `example/` directory and attempted to run the script `python3.6 example.py`. 
It complained about a missing `module` `piecash`. I've attempted to install it with `sudo -H pip install piecash` but I keep getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'piecash`. `Stdout` from `pip` looks like:

```
$ sudo -H pip install piecash
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
Requirement already satisfied: piecash in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from piecash) (0.4.43+16.4.20170613.0ubuntu1)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy-Utils>=0.31 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from piecash) (0.34.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tzlocal in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from piecash) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from piecash) (2014.10)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy>=1.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from piecash) (1.0.11)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from SQLAlchemy-Utils>=0.31->piecash) (1.10.0)
```

Can anyone help me get past this? One thing is, I've also had to install `pathlib` and it seemed like the `pip` command (`sudo apt-get install python-pathlib`)would not satisfy the requirement and I had to install it using `apt-get` instead...
This machine is running on Ubuntu 16.04

I also have installed the `python3-pandas` package.

Comment: Run `pip -V` and check what Python version it prints, it looks like the default `pip` command is aliased to Python 3.5 on your machine. If you need the package for Python 3.6, use the correct pip: `pip3.6 install piecash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Requirement already satisfied: piecash in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (1.0.0)

You installed `piecash` with Python 3.5 but ran the example with Python 3.6. Two different Pythons. Use one or the other.

```
sudo python3.5 -m pip install piecash
python3.5 example.py
```

or

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install piecash
python3.6 example.py
```